# JavaScript create csv column names

Tags: javascript, csv

I am generating a CSV file in JavaScript:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charget=uft-8,Data1, Data2, Data3 /n Data1, Data2, Data3";
```

I am just wondering how do I add column names? 
My data is appearing properly.
I am just looking to add some column names. Is this possible?

Comment: There's nothing special about column headings in a CSV file - it's just the first row with labels in instead of data.

Comment: The header columns are usually the first row, but there isn't any special mark up. For example when you open a csv in excel I think it asks you whether the first row is a header row